# Can I trace encoded/crypted script activity?

Tags: php, bash, logging, encryption

Is it possible to log or trace crypted script, to see what changes it does on my pc?  At start there is a sh script that loads custom php extension to php, what decrypts install.php file, then it loads crypted php file in terminal and installs software, but it doesn't show me exact info what it does in terminal. I can't see install script source also (which is the whole point of encryption of course).

Comment: `strace` will show you what it's doing at a syscall level. At some point the script will probably write or pipe the unencrypted php file, and `strace` will dump its content too.

Comment: Thank you, this strace if pretty useful program. One question , i see one line in log that seems to be start of source code of php, can i expand it somehow, i only see small part of it. read(3, "<?php\n\n//#Company SoftWare\n"..., 4096) = 4096

Comment: You can use `strace -s 100000` to show the first 100k characters instead of the default 32.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it now shows more info, but too bad it still shows crypted source of php. I guess it is not possible to see decoded php source using strace. But strace is a good solution to see what programs/scripts to in server.